# How to serve svg as a link in rest controller?

Tags: java, spring

I want to serve svg icons as a link in my json.

But I have a few questions.

1) How can I contain svg file in database and java class?

2) How can I serve svg file? I mean I want to serve it to get link..

3) ..and put this link to the json like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Some name",
    "linkToIcon": "https://server.com/schools/0/icon.svg"
}
```

Actually I need a java type to either svg or png or jpeg images..

Comment: Isn't svg a text file ?

Comment: Is it? I am not sure, that's why I am asking you.

Comment: But what when I have png image?